# How to pass parameter/prompt & schedule the webi report using SAP BO 4.0 SDK in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webi

I am able to schedule a webi report using C#. But can't able to pass prompt/parameter into the report. Please help

```
 public string GetReport(int _reportId)
        {
            EnterpriseSession ceSession = EntSession;

            EnterpriseService ceEnterpriseService;
            InfoStore ceInfoStore;
            CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoObjects ceReportObjects;
            CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoObject ceReportObject;
            Report ceReport;
            string sQuery;
            try
            {
                //grab the Enterprise session
                if (ceSession != null)
                {
                   // ceSession = (EnterpriseSession)Session["ceSession"];

                    //Create the infostore object
                    ceEnterpriseService = ceSession.GetService("", "InfoStore");
                    ceInfoStore = new InfoStore(ceEnterpriseService);

                    //Create query to grab the desired report
                    sQuery = "Select top 1 SI_ID, SI_PROCESSINFO.SI_PROMPTS,* From CI_INFOOBJECTS Where  SI_ID=" + _reportId + " AND SI_INSTANCE=0 ";
                    ceReportObjects = ceInfoStore.Query(sQuery);

                    //check for returned reports
                    if (ceReportObjects.Count > 0)
                    {
                        ceReportObject = ceReportObjects[1];

                        //ceReport = (Report)ceReportObject;

                        //Create an interface to the scheduling options for the report.
                       CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.SchedulingInfo ceSchedulingInfo;
                        ceSchedulingInfo = ceReportObject.SchedulingInfo;
                        //run the report right now
                        ceSchedulingInfo.RightNow = true;
                        //run the report once only
                        ceSchedulingInfo.Type = CeScheduleType.ceScheduleTypeOnce;

                        //When scheduling to all destinations except the printer, you must first retrieve 
                        //the appropriate destination object. Each destination InfoObject is stored in the 
                        //CMS system table (CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS) under the Destination Plugins folder

                        //Retrieve the DiskUnmanaged Plugin from CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS
                      CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoObjects ceDestinationObjects;
                      CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.InfoObject ceDestinationObject;
                        ceDestinationObjects = ceInfoStore.Query("Select * from CI_SYSTEMOBJECTS Where SI_NAME = 'CrystalEnterprise.DiskUnmanaged'");
                        ceDestinationObject = ceDestinationObjects[1];
                        //ReportFormatOptions ceReportFormatOpts;
                        //ceReportFormatOpts = ceReportObject.ReportFormatOptions;


                        //Create the DestinationPlugin object
                        DestinationPlugin ceDisk = new DestinationPlugin(ceDestinationObject.PluginInterface);



                        DiskUnmanagedOptions ceDiskOpts = new DiskUnmanagedOptions(ceDisk.ScheduleOptions);

                        ceDiskOpts.DestinationFiles.Add(@"" + Utility.BO.BOReportFolder + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy_MM_dd") + "_" + ceReportObject.Title.ToString() + ".pdf");

                        CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Destination ceDestination;
                        ceDestination = ceSchedulingInfo.Destination;
                        ceDestination.SetFromPlugin(ceDisk);
                        List<string> reportParameterList = new List<string>();


                        Report rpt = ceReportObject as Report;
                        if (rpt != null)
                        {
                            //for each (CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Internal.ISReportParameter parameter in (CrystalDecisions.Enterprise.Desktop.Internal.ISReportParameter)rpt.ReportParameters)
                            //{
                            //    reportParameterList.Add(new ReportParameter(parameter));
                            //}
                            for (int i = 0; i < rpt.ReportParameters.Count; i++)
                            {
                                rpt.ReportParameters[i].DefaultValues[0].SingleValue.Value = "";
                               // ISReportParameter isp =(ISReportParameter) rpt.ReportParameters[i];
                               // reportParameterList.Add(rpt.ReportParameters[i].ToString());
                            }
                        }




                        //ReportParameters ceParameters;
                        //ReportParameterValue ceParamValue;
                        //ReportParameters rpt = ceReportObject as ReportParameters ;

                        //if (rpt != null)
                        //{


                        //    //ceParameters = ((Report)ceReportObject).ReportParameters;
                        //    foreach (ReportParameter ceParameter in rpt.ReportParameters)
                        //    {
                        //        ceParamValue = ceParameter.CreateSingleValue();
                        //        // ceParamValue.SingleValue.Value = "Time(12,15,15)";
                        //        //ceParameter.CurrentValues.Add(ceParamValue);
                        //    }
                        //}



                        //schedule report
                        ceInfoStore.Schedule(ceReportObjects);

                        return "Report Scheduled Successfully with an Object ID of : " + ceDestinationObject.ID.ToString()
                         + "<br>Report Scheduled to the following location: " + ceDiskOpts.DestinationFiles[1].ToString();
                    }

                }
                else
                {
                    //no Enterprise session available
                    return ("No Valid Enterprise Session Found!<br>"
                    + "Please click <a href='Index.aspx'>here</a> to return to the logon page.<br>");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                throw new Exception(
                "There was an error scheduling the report: <br>" +
                err.Message.ToString() + "<br>" +
                "Please click <a href='Index.aspx'>here</a> to return to the logon page.<br>");
            }
            return "";
        }
```

Please help to pass paramater to WEBI Report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got response from SAP Team

In BI4.0, ReportEngine is deprecated for scheduling webi report with prompt, the replacement solution is RESTful Web Service SDK.
You can check detailed description in the link: https://blogs.sap.com/2014/03/13/migration-guide-for-businessobjects-enterprise-sdk-custom-applications/

About the RESTful Web Service SDK, you can find more useful information in this link: https://archive.sap.com/documents/docs/DOC-51800

Comment: Are you able to retrieve completed instance via REST? I'm having trouble with that and the documentation only implies viewing it in OpenDocument or creating a Publication and scheduling that to disk.